# Equality proof of function $g_N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{x+n}$

Tags: functions, summation

I have a function
$$ g_N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{x+n} $$
How can I prove that this function is odd, thus $ g_N(-x) = -g_N(x)$ ?

Comment: In addition to the algebraic answers, there is the simple intuition that your function consists of N + 1 poles located at -N, -N + 1, ..., 0, 1, ... N. These are all just horizontal translations of $1/x$ (a well-known odd function), symmetrically placed around 0, added together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-g_N(x)=-\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{x+n} = \sum_{n=-N}^N -\frac{1}{x+n} =\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{-x+n}  $$
$$g_N(-x)=\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{-x+n}  $$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  $$\frac{1}{-x + n} = -\frac{1}{x - n}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Note that $$\sum_{n=M}^K a_n = \sum_{n=-K}^{-M} a_{-n}.$$

Comment: +1 If I had any votes left, I think both our hints combine as a full answer

Comment: @muzzlator Yep :)

Answer (score 3):

Fold the sum in half at the middle ($n = 0$):
$$
\begin{align}
g_N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^{n=N} \frac{1}{x+n} &= \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{n=1}^{n=N} \left( \frac{1}{x-n} + \frac{1}{x+n} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{n=1}^{n=N} \frac{2x}{x^2 - n^2}
\end{align}
$$
Now, you can verify directly that $g_N(-x) = -g_N(x)$.